# Unable to Expand and Collapse TableViewCell in Swift

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I have taken `two prototype cells called CategoryTableCell and SubCategoryTableCell in tableview`

Initially, I need to show all `CategoryTableCell` data in `TableView`. Here if I click `CategoryTableCell` then I need to show that Category's subcategories in `SubCategoryTableCell`. How to do that?

I need to hide all subcategories. If I click any one category from `CategoryTableCell` then I need to its subcategories.

Code:

```
extension CategoryVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.activeCategories?.count ?? 0 : 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return self.activeCategories?[section].sub_categories?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SubCategoryTableCell", for: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        let activesubCat = self.activeCategories?[indexPath.section].sub_categories
        let indexData = activesubCat?[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.lblTitle?.text = langType == .en ? indexData?.details?.first?.title : indexData?.details?[1].title
        return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    
        let view = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryTableCell") as! CategoryTableCell
        let indexData = self.activeCategories?[section]
        view.btnDetails?.tag = section
        view.lblTitle?.text = langType == .en ? indexData?.details?.first?.title : indexData?.details?[1].title
        return view
   

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return isFromFilter ? 40 : 0
}
```

With the code, I am getting all categories in red colour and subcategories in dark grey colour text. But, here cell is not expanding and collapse. I need to show all red colour text initially. Here if I tap on the cell then it has to expand and show all grey colour text. How to do that? Please do help with the code.

**o/p: coming like this with above code**

[![screenshot][1]][1]

**EDIT**

JSON Model:

```
public class Category_json {
public var id : Int?
public var status : String?
public var sub_categories : Array<Sub_categories>?
var isExpanded = true

required public init?(dictionary: NSDictionary) {

    id = dictionary["id"] as? Int
    status = dictionary["status"] as? String
    if (dictionary["sub_categories"] != nil) { sub_categories = Sub_categories.modelsFromDictionaryArray(array: dictionary["sub_categories"] as? NSArray ?? NSArray()) }
    if (dictionary["details"] != nil) { details = Details.modelsFromDictionaryArray(array: dictionary["details"] as? NSArray ?? NSArray()) }
}

public func dictionaryRepresentation() -> NSDictionary {

    let dictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

    dictionary.setValue(self.id, forKey: "id")
    dictionary.setValue(self.status, forKey: "status")

    return dictionary
 }
}
```

and `public var activeCategories : Array<Category_json>?`

**EDIT2:**

```
@objc func expandMe() {
     print("expand me")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to your `activeCategories` array 's model

```
var isExpanded = true
```

Then inside `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
guard let item = self.activeCategories?[section] else { return 0 }
return item.isExpanded ? (item.sub_categories?.count ?? 0) : 0
```

Then play with `isExpanded` and refresh the table

**Edit**

Inside `viewForHeaderInSection`

```
 let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryTableCell") as! CategoryTableCell 
 button.tag = section
```

Then inside action

```
@objc headerClicked(_ sender:UIButton) {
    let section  = sender.tag
    guard let item = self.activeCategories?[section] else { return 0 }
    item.isExpanded.toggle()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```